# Sealing crawl space vents in Pacific Northwest?

Tags: drainage, sump-pump, crawlspace

I just had a perimeter drain and sump pump installed in our crawlspace because it flooded frequently and severely during the rainy seasons. Before, I was under the impression that leaving the crawlspace vents open was the way to go in this climate (very wet winter/spring, very dry summers). Now, with the drainage system in place, I'm leaning toward closing off the vents, since (if the drain/pump system works) there will be no more standing water, and thus much lower humidity levels, and it would slow down the inevitable fouling of the new plastic sheeting from dust and such.

So, to seal or not to seal?

Thank you

Steve

Answer (score 2):

Oregon resident here. You should keep the vents open if closed off things like radon have no place to go. Trapped moisture will cause rot, You may keep the water out but it will still be damp and it needs air flow.

Comment: You're not saying that radon will cause rot...

Comment: No radon can cause health issues. With vents sealed it really forces it into the living space.reworded so answer is clear.

Comment: Yeah, radon can definitely be a factor in causing lung cancer and the only way to reduce radon levels if you have a radon issue is through vents. Trapped moisture that can't escape will definitely contribute to rot. I believe this depends a fair degree on the local climate. In the southeast, for example, venting might let as much moisture in as out.

Comment: Even if you don't reduce humidity much, pollutants like radon and other gases should be vented, and you may reduce mold spores, etc.

Comment: This is a bit anecdotal at this point coming from me, but I've read pieces by engineers/builders in the deep south saying that venting attics in that area, for instance, can do more harm than good. In fact, I'll just go Google it... <computing>. Yeah, this is along the lines of what I remember  ;-)   https://buildingscience.com/documents/insights/bsi-015-top-ten-dumb-things-to-do-in-the-south

Comment: @Craig the Pacific North West has issues we normally have rain 12 months a year (only a few days in the summer months) a crawl space is much different than an attics but attics are required to be vented here also.

Comment: I lived in Seattle for a decade. ;-)  I might have thrown a a curve in the whole thing talking about the southeast (where I've also spent a fair amount of time). There was another question on the same day asking whether to vent an enclosed bit of attic in the southeast. The problem *there* is that the air is consistently warm and humid almost all of the time, so it's suffused with moisture that condenses onto and soaks into everything. There's more variation, less humidity, and less heat to turn every temperature differential into a condensation surface in the Pacific Northwest.